# How to configure and use the dialogflow V2 NodeJS client library in Angular7-Typescript or Ionic v4?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular7, dialogflow-es, ionic4

I want to integrate my Dialogflow chatbot with my existing ionic4 App using Angular Typescript but I'm having problems importing it for use within my project. How best can I import the dialogflow NodeJS client for use in my Ionic or Angular App ??

I started a blank Ionic4 Angular project and installed the dialogflow client library:

```
npm install dialogflow
```

and I have also installed the dialogflow typescript using:

```
npm install --save @types/dialogflow
```

I have also updated my **tsconfig.app.json** to be;

```
"extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node","dialogflow"]
  },
```

**Method 1** : *the initialisation in [dialogflow docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/libraries/nodejs)*

```
dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
```

**Method 2**: *Alternate initialisation*

```
import { SessionsClient } from 'dialogflow';

constructor(public platform: Platform) {

    const sessionClient = new SessionsClient();
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath('project-ID', 'session-ID');
}
```

In Both cases when I try to use the library, this error is coming up

**On the web App it's showing this error**:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/operationsClient.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './operations_client_config' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/google-gax/build/src'
```

**On the console its showing this error**:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/operationsClient.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './operations_client_config' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/google-gax/build/src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/gtoken/build/src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/request/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/forever-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/dev/MobileApps/goatChat/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

What am I doing wrong or how can I correct it ?